# Change default button color from grey to white android

Tags: android, button

I have a cardview. The button default color is grey. I want it to look like the right side image(like the blessings). This right one has been created setting backgroundtint to white but in older versions its still shows grey.[image]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/programm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/hotpink"
        android:onClick="openNextActivity">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawable="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Programme"
            android:textColor="@color/hotpink"
            android:onClick="openNextActivity"
            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

If i change the background of the button to white the entire color changes to white:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/programm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|right"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/hotpink"
        android:onClick="openNextActivity">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawable="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Programme"
            android:textColor="@color/hotpink"
            android:onClick="openNextActivity"
            />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

As per google search, this default grey color is set in some theme.I probably need to overwrite some theme and set some attribute. But I am not sure what do I need to change.

Answer (score 2):

### Try this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button Text"
    android:theme="@style/myButtonTheme"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

### set this `myButtonTheme` in your `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="myButtonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#5552f1</item>
</style>
```

[ set your desired background color in `colorButtonNormal` ]

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested it for this kind of situation, but i think something like this can work
you can create a `background.xml` in your drawable directory and set it as background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<item>
    <shape>
        <!-- set the shadow color here -->
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#77000000" />

        <!-- setting the thickness of shadow (positive value will give shadow on that side) -->

        <padding
            android:bottom="3dp"
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

things you can try with this is that you can set the **shadow color** the color you want or something else that i had in mind was set the opacity of shadow color to zero so that it would be transparent and you can set its thickness by the **paddings** of the shadow

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In yout styles define:

```
<style name="BlueButtonTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored</item>

    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/disabledButtonColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/enabledButtonColor</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">1</item>
    <!-- button text color-->

    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/colored_button_text_color</item>
</style>
```

And in your layout xml file:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:enabled="false"

    android:theme="@style/BlueWhiteButtonTheme"
    android:text="@string/buttonLabel"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set background for button in your layout

```
<Button
android:background="@android:color:white"
</Button>
```